# Mostrar Bootstrap Modal la primera vez al cargar la página SIN JQUERY

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

Buscando por StackOverflow encontré [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68218076/15465836) que muestra un modal de **Bootstrap 5** al cargar la página sin usar Jquery, sin embargo se muestra cada que se hace refresca la página, y quisiera saber cómo hacer solamente salga 1 vez.

```js
var myModal = document.getElementById('staticBackdrop');
var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModal)
modal.show()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" id="waitDialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   Some Stuff. 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Me parece que es con LocalStorage, porque así [aparece en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700900/15465836). Sin embargo la respuesta está usando JQuery y no logré adaptarla al código actual.

Comment: Buenas, me temo que lo que quieres hacer no se puede sin usar jquery ya que cómo sabe el componente cuando se tiene que mostrar u ocultar sin ningún tipo de lógica. Ten en cuenta el html es un lenguaje de marcas sin ningún tipo de lógica alguna. Deberías usar cookies o la memoria caché y utlizar jquery para ello

Comment: por lo que veo en la respuesta del enlace solo tienes que buscar el equivalente de $(document).ready de jquery  en vanilla js eso es todo para que te funcione sin jquery

Comment: Puedes hacer una logica externa, y usar por ejemplo `SessionStorage` para eso, para eso debes `setear` una variable `visita=1` por ejemplo, de ahi si recarga la pagina y encuentra ese `value` en el local ya no ejecutas el `modal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como hacer tu codigo con un `SessionStorage`, espero te sirva.

```js
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal')),
      btnCerrrar = document.getElementById('boton-cerrar');

window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{

  let visita = sessionStorage.getItem('visita');

  if(visita == null) myModal.show();

});

btnCerrrar.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  myModal.hide();
  sessionStorage.setItem('visita', 1);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button id="boton-cerrar" type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-kjU+l4N0Yf4ZOJErLsIcvOU2qSb74wXpOhqTvwVx3OElZRweTnQ6d31fXEoRD1Jy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

En este caso agrego tambien el `EventListener` del boton que cierra el modal, con esto aseguras que el usuario añada el `SessionStorage` y que el modal no se dispare cargando la pagina de nuevo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Funciona perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

siguiendo la respuesta del enlace sin jQuery quedaría asi

```
   <html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("myModal"), {});
      function window_onload() {
       if (sessionStorage.getItem('myModal') !== 'true') {
        modal.show();
        sessionStorage.setItem('myModal','true');     
       }
      }
     </script>

  </head>
  <body onLoad="window_onload()">

  </body>
  </html>
```